# ActionMailer message delivery content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have the ability to send email to a user if a certain user has requested interest in their product. In my email I want to include certain information that is pulled from users but at the moment I am getting errors because it states that they are undefined despite these lines being used elsewhere in my application. I shall copy the email below and anything between the <% %> is what I wish to include and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction and tell me which are those that are correct and are not. Any help would be wonderful. The message I want to send is as followed:

```
Hello <%@user.username%>

The user <% current_user.username %> has registered an interest in the following product of  yours:

<% @game.game_name %>
<% @game.console %>
<% @game.genre %>

The user <% current_user.usernames %> has the following games for offer:

<% current_user.game.game_name %>
<% current_user.game.game_name %>
<% current_user.game.game_name %>

To view <% current_user.username %> profile click <% link_to "here", current_user.show %>
If you wish to contact the user by email then contact the following email <% current_user.email %>.
```

I hope that makes sense. In order to give further insight in to what I have, I have a users table that includes user information and a game table that has games information with a user_id foreign key. Users have a has_many with games and games belongs_to user.

UPDATE

```
  class GameTrade < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "christopher@aol.com"

    def game_interest(user)
      @user = user
      @game = game
      mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Game Interest"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you include your mailer method here as well? I'd like to see how you're setting up @game.

Comment: Hi Ben, I have updated my post with my mailer method. I did have a line under '@user = user' that said '@game = game' but that would not work.

Comment: right, so you're not setting `@game` in the game_interest mailer function, so it won't be set in your view. You can either pass in `game` as a method param, or get it some other way (like @user.game if that's a relationship in your app)

Comment: I have the above updated mailer but when I click the button I get undefined local variable or method 'game'

Comment: you're setting `@game` to `game`, but `game` was never set. You can't just make up variables and expect them to have a value (I know it looks like there are several 'magic' variables, like `current_user`, but those are actually methods that are defined somewhere and within the current binding). So game_interest probably needs to take a second method parameter, `game`. You could do `@game = Game.new`, although that wouldn't make sense in terms of the application logic.

Comment: Yes, if I was to add the suggested Game.new then it would deliver but all fields marked as <% %> don't appear. How do I declare a second method parameter in actionmailer?

Comment: Never mind, I managed to sort it now on that side. Still wondering how to do current_user though

Comment: Fixed it all :) got current_user working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html, action mailer "inherits from Abstract Controller", but not from your ApplicationController, so I wouldn't expect `current_user` to be defined. Also, where's `user` coming from? Just like controllers and their relevant views, the common practice is to define instance variables like `@user`, `@game`, etc. in your mailer, and then access these in the views.

If you think about it, it doesn't make sense to have a `current_user` here, because if you start sending lots of emails, you'll want to make email sending to an asynchronous (e.g. with delayed_job or resque). In that case, there is no current user making a request, since it's no longer part of the request/response cycle.

Comment: I have updated the @user part as I accidentally excluded the at when I typed it. That part works fine, but the game part does not work. I keep receiving an error stating undefined method 'name of column' so undefined method 'game_name' etc.